# How to replace text & URLs in shortcode output

Tags: php, wordpress, post, geolocation, geoip

I'm trying to add a custom function to my WordPress blog that will replace "bigalspets.com" with "bigalspets.ca" in all post text and/or hyperlinks, if the visitor's Geolocation is based in Canada.

- If visitor IP = Canadian, replace "bigalspets.com" with "bigalspets.ca" in all rendered post content (including links and content generated by other plugins!).

I'm using the [GeoIP Detection plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/) to get GeoIP information, and the Code Snippets plugin to add custom functions that run only on the website's front-end.

The function I have so far is this:

```
function replace_if_canada( $text ) {
   $geoip = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
   if ( $geoip->country->isoCode == 'CA' ) {
     return str_replace('bigalspets.com', 'bigalspets.ca', $text);
   }
}

function replace_if_canada_shortcodes( $output ) {
   $geoip = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
   if ( $geoip->country->isoCode == 'CA' ) {
     echo str_replace('bigalspets.com', 'bigalspets.ca', $output);
   }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_if_canada', 999);
add_filter('do_shortcode_tag', 'replace_if_canada_shortcodes', 999);
```

Here's a url of a WP post where the function should work:
https://eheimsupport.com/blog/themed-tanks/items/canyon-island/

THE PROBLEM: the 'replace_if_canada_shortcodes' part of my code isn't working i.e. **the code replaces text/urls in normal post content but not in the Image Map Pro shortcode's output!**

If you hover over one of the little "i" icons on the image map in the content body, you'll see product URLs. Those are not changing from .com to .ca...

How do I get the function to apply to EVERYTHING on ALL posts and pages. Please help! :(